# C# HDInsight MapReduce pass arguments to mapper

Tags: c#, azure, hadoop, mapreduce, azure-hdinsight

To execute mapreduce you have to pass the mapper and reducer/combiner types, hence they must have parameterless constructor. So there is no way you can dependency inject any properties to the mapper or reducer entities via the constructor or mapper method?

I'm trying to avoid creating multiple mappers that do the exact same thing only that they are looking for a different property in a json string input.

Taken from msdn blog for illustration. The mapper converts inputline we assume as json string to an object. Takes out "some property" to map. The problem here is how can we inject that "some property" so we can control the behavior of the mapper without having to create multiple implementations of it.

```
public class MySimpleMapper : MapperBase

{

    public override void Map(string inputLine, MapperContext context)

    {

        //interpret the incoming line as an integer value

        SomeObject obj = JsonConvert.Serialize<SomeObject>(inputLine);
        int value = obj.Properties["some property"];

        //determine whether value is even or odd

        string key = (value % 2 == 0) ? “even” : “odd”;

        //output key assignment with value

        context.EmitKeyValue(key, value.ToString());

    }

}
```

The reducer class that takes the mapped objects from the mapper.

```
public class MySimpleReducer : ReducerCombinerBase

{

    public override void Reduce(

        string key, IEnumerable<string> values, ReducerCombinerContext context

        )

    {

        //initialize counters

        int myCount = 0;

        int mySum = 0;



        //count and sum incoming values

        foreach (string value in values)

        {

            mySum += int.Parse(value);

            myCount++;

        }

        //output results

        context.EmitKeyValue(key, myCount + “t” + mySum);

    }
```

Notice how we give it the type of mapper and reducer, hence there needs to be a parameter-less constructor.

```
        //output results

        context.EmitKeyValue(key, myCount + “t” + mySum);

    }

//establish job configuration

        HadoopJobConfiguration myConfig = new HadoopJobConfiguration();

        myConfig.InputPath = “/demo/simple/in”;

        myConfig.OutputFolder = “/demo/simple/out”;



        //connect to cluster

        Uri myUri = new Uri(“http://localhost”);

        string userName = “hadoop”;

        string passWord = null;

        IHadoop myCluster = Hadoop.Connect(myUri, userName, passWord);



        //execute mapreduce job

        MapReduceResult jobResult =

            myCluster.MapReduceJob.Execute<MySimpleMapper, MySimpleReducer>(myConfig);
```

Comment: Hi, can you add some sample code to illustrate your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the context to pass variables into your map/reduce classes. Here is an example of submitting a jar via powershell and reading the key in your Java M/R program

PowerShell submission:

```
$defines = @{"parser.batch.id" = $batchID}  
$jobDef = New-AzureHDInsightMapReduceJobDefinition -JarFile $jarPath -ClassName "com.microsoft.myclass" -Defines $defines -JobName "Parser" -StatusFolder "Parser/$batchID"
$job = Start-AzureHDInsightJob -Cluster $clusterName -JobDefinition $jobDef -verbose -Credential $clusterCred**
```

From your M/R job

```
conf = contex.getConfigutation();
batchID = conf.get(Keys.PARSER_BATCH_ID.getKey());
```

Resources:
http://www.andrewsmoll.com/3-hacks-for-hadoop-and-hdinsight-clusters/
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mostlytrue/2014/04/10/merging-small-files-on-hdinsight/

Comment: The C# library does not support this: http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce/src/MapReduce/Microsoft.Hadoop.MapReduce/BasicStreaming/Context/ContextBase.cs

Comment: hmm You could store the configuration file in something like blob storage and retrieve it from the M/R instance. It feels wrong but I'm not aware of another way to pass variables into a M/R instance

Comment: Yeah that is hacky. Well I'm just going to tell the guys at Microsoft. Likely there is already a pull request out there to fix this.